# strip characters from char array pass as pointer in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, char

any suggestion on how to strip characters from char array pass as pointer in C++. i must use memcpy function to copy.

```
void foo(char *test)
{
char a[1] = {0};
char b[1] = {0};
char c[1]= {0};

memcpy(&a,&test[0],1);
memcpy(&b,&test[1],1);
memcpy(&c,&test[2],1);

cout << a <<endl;
cout << b <<endl;
cout << c <<endl;
}

int main()
{
char uibuffer[4] = "ABC";
foo(uibuffer);
return 0;
}
```

the current output is:

```
ABC��
BC��
C��
```

desired output is:

```
A
B
C
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
void foo(char *test)
{
/* Please note, you need to add one extra byte here for a terminator */
char a[2] = {0};
char b[2] = {0};
char c[2]= {0};

memcpy(&a,&test[0],1);
memcpy(&b,&test[1],1);
memcpy(&c,&test[2],1);

cout << a <<endl;
cout << b <<endl;
cout << c <<endl;
}

int main()
{
char uibuffer[4] = "ABC";
foo(uibuffer);
return 0;
}
```

OR

Think about improving your code by getting rid of arrays and memory copying. Simple `char a = buffer[x]` will do the trick.

Comment: @werewindle: No, it will be a pointer to an array, which is the same thing as a pointer to the first character.

Comment: @Benjamin Lindley, pointer to array - is simply `a`. `&a` will be point to pointer to array. Wee need `memcpy(a,&test[0])` or `memcpy(&a[0],&test[0])` or `memcpy(a,test)`, which is the same.

Comment: @werewindle: No.  a is an array.  It can decay to a pointer to char, but it is still an array.  &a is a pointer to an array.  Test it out.  Yes, `memcpy(a,&test[0],1)` will work, but so will `memcpy(&a,&test[0],1)`

Comment: Ok, it was my fault. `&a` and `a` points to the same memory. I need to reread C specs :)

Comment: Slight correction to *"which is the same thing as a pointer to the first character"* -- I should have said, it's the same *address* as a pointer to the first character, but it's not the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

since you haven't created \0 terminated strings do:

```
cout << a[0] <<endl;
cout << b[0] <<endl;
cout << c[0] <<endl;
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't make a, b and c an array. Probably won't compile but to illustrate.

```
void foo(char *test)
{
char a = 0;
char b = 0;
char c = 0;

memcpy(&a,&test[0],1);
memcpy(&b,&test[1],1);
memcpy(&c,&test[2],1);

cout << a <<endl;
cout << b <<endl;
cout << c <<endl;
}

int main()
{
char uibuffer[4] = "ABC";
foo(uibuffer);
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't make them arrays:

```
char a = test[0];
char b = test[1];
char c = test[2];
```

You can still use memcpy, if you must, just as you are now.